# Symfony2 : clear cache don't generate required file EntityManager_XXXX.php (for doctrine)

Tags: symfony, caching, doctrine

After a cache:clear I have this in php log :

PHP Warning:  require_once(/var/www/mysite/releases/20150706130613/app/cache/prod/jms_diextra/doctrine/**EntityManager_56274d8036816.php**): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/mysite/releases/20150706130613/app/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainer.php on line 279

I check the file list in app/cache/prod/jms_diextra/doctrine/, I find EntityManager_XXXX.php where XXXX.php is allways different from 56274d8036816 !! So i duplicate the existing file with the required file name and then it works !! The strange thing is it' allways the same file name (56274d8036816) symfony need and never find/generate !!

I don't want to manually create the needed file each time I clear the cache :( what's going wrong ??

Comment: Sound like a permission issue. Try to delete folders cache/dev/ and cache/prod

Comment: I did it, but it still won't work! If it's a permission issue why I can find EntityManager_XXXX.php ? Sometimes I find may on them, but on matches the missing file !

Comment: I have the same problem, did you found what went on ?

Comment: yes : the problem is not from symfony but from the server's reverse proxy (or proxy cache, I don't remember) ! I just asked the server admin to disable the cache (I think it was Varnish) and every thing went fine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add permissions to cache directory

```
chmod 777 -R cache
```

Comment: I did it now but I have allways the same error : EntityManager_56274d8036816.php ...failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue.
The other comments are correct, here are the steps:

1. Delete all files/directories in your cache directory.
2. chmod -R 777 cache
3. php app/console cache:warmup

This should succesfully generate the cache.